# Creating multiple stages for single url in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

So I know you can manually do this in AWS, but I want to be able to achieve this functionality:

```
https://myurl.com/test/
https://myurl.com/dev/
https://myurl.com/prod/
```

Rather than three completely new endpoints like so:

```
https://cojn6cbcd9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/handler
https://uojn6cbce7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/handler
https://abcn6cbce7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/handler
```

Looks like someone asked this about two years ago and sounds like at the time it was not possible to do, but serverless since then has been working on it? https://forum.serverless.com/t/api-gateway-same-base-urls-for-my-apis/674

EDIT: To elaborate in aws we do not want 3 different endpoints (api-gateways) for each stage being made. We want one endpoint (api-gateway) with 3 stages being made underneath it

Comment: Yes, if I understand your question correctly, it is definitely feasible. We have url:s like that (myurl.com/endpoint) in AWS (with AWS Lambda) deployed with Serverless Framework. Exactly how it is done should be in the examples and manual from serverless...if you cannot find it then I can share some code with you. But it should work.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz Checkout the edit I made and let me know if this is still feasible! If so we have gone through multiple examples and could not get them to work.

Comment: The way we do it is, I think, one endpoint with 3 stages for example `dev.myurl.com/handler`, `test.myurl.com/handler` and `prod.myurl.com/handler`. They are three separate deployments. We use GitLab CI/CD to deploy it. Not sure if this helps you...?

Comment: Yeah so we need one deploy, so in our AWS we want to see only one gateway with three stages. We can manually do it, but can't figure out with serverless. It seems like people have work arounds (as you put above), but that still makes 3 separate gateways in our AWS.